# Interpolation on set of points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, interpolation

Is it possible to perform Interpolation in QGIS with input as a vector layer which has a set of points collected following a specified path?

Comment: Yes is the short answer, but can you be a little more specific as to what the data represent and the sort of output you require as this will influence the approach to interpolation and should give you a better set of suggestions to your question.

Comment: i have collected temperature data by walking around a parcel boundary.now what i have with me is the sampled data at 10m distance around a square plot. how can i perform interpolation on this data??

Answer (score 4):

QGIS documention actually gives [examples](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) (one includes temperature data) using Inverse Distance Weighted and another example using a TIN.
be sure to look at "Common problems / things to be aware of" - per the linked page above:

- 1. Evaluate the sample data. Do this to get an idea on how data are distributed in the area, as this may provide hints on which interpolation method to use.
- 2. Apply an interpolation method which is most suitable to both the sample data and the study objectives. When you are in doubt, try several methods, if available.
- 3. Compare the results and find the best result and the most suitable method. This may look like a time consuming process at the beginning. However, as you gain experience and knowledge of different interpolation methods, the time required for generating the most suitable surface will be greatly reduced.

there is also another [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30905/how-to-interpolate-temperature-correctly) about interpolating temperature data.

i'm still familiarizing myself with QGIS (stuck in ArcGIS world for too long) - but by hitting 'Processing->toolbox', i was able to search IDW or triangulation (or spline, kriging, etc.) to get a list of potential tools.

Answer (score 3):

When interpolating points, I tend to personally use **Heatmaps** (download the Heatmap plugin from *Plugins* > *Manage and Install plugins...*). You can then find the option in *Raster* > *Heatmap*:

[image: Heatmap plugin]

I made a simple point layer in the form of a square and ran the Heatmap function. I then set the colouring filter in the *Layer Properties*:

[image: Layer Properties]

And I get this as a result:

[image: Result]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You for you reply. I would like to know about Interpolation using IDW.

Comment: Thank You for you reply. I would like to know about Interpolation using IDW.This is what I got after performing Interpolation in ArcGIS <img src="https://plus.google.com/photos/103633775360774873016/albums/6069971741042795313/6069971748526552050?pid=6069971748526552050&oid=103633775360774873016" width="100" height="100">

Comment: No problem buddy, the first link @fluidmotion posted describes using IDW. You can easily use your favourite search engine to find more information regarding IDW, [this](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/51-inverse-distance-weighting-idw-interpolation-using-qgis.html) is the first link I received which gives a basic tutorial.